# Memory-mapped co-processor interface

Tags: hardware, processor

I have a very basic question. The architecture I am studying offers a memory-mapped
co-processor Interface. Could somebody confirm that I understand this concept correctly:

If I have a co-processor attached, then some memory region on the bus system is reserved
to communicate with the co-processor, i.e. to send and read data, execute commands, etc.

Alternatively, there is the tightly coupled approach, I assume there is another mechanism used to communicate with the co-processor and the overhead of this is less because the co-processor is closer to the host, is that right?

Thank you very much for some insight into this trivial problem ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding is fundamentally correct, except what is reserved is a piece of the *address space*, that probably doesn't correspond to any "real" memory anywhere, it's simply a way of using the same mechanism one would use to read and write memory locations to read and write data to/from the co-processor, usually.

I don't think it's necessarily true that exposing a co-processor in a non-memory-mapped way will be more efficient.  There could be some kind of virtual instructions implemented, for example, but that is not necessarily lower on overheads.  I think it's very difficult to make general statements about this kind of thing without reference to specifics of the architecture and implementation.

Perhaps the Wikipedia article on [Memory-Mapped IO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) will allow you to verify that your assumptions are correct, as co-processor communication is pretty much just normal "device IO" as far as the CPU is concerned.